# Extract a URL from a row with multiple URLS in it

Tags: python, string, pandas, extract

I am trying to extract a URL from a row that has multiple URLs listed.

Specifically, I want to select the first instance of `twitter.com/dog_rates/xxxxxxx` from the row and remove the remaining data.

Examples of the text that needs to be extracted

**INPUT**

```
1. twitter.com/dog_rates/status/892420643555336193/photo/1 (desired version)

2. www.gofundme.com/3yd6y1c,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/878281511006478336/photo/1

3. m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=1888712391349242&id=1506300642923754&refsrc=ht.co%2FURVffYPPjY&_rdr,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/812503143955202048/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/812503143955202048/photo/1

4. www.gofundme.com/sams-smile,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/810984652412424192/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1

5. twitter.com/dog_rates/status/888804989199671297/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/888804989199671297/photo/1
```

I have attempted to extract the URLs using slicing but run into the problem that there are multiple URLs of varying lengths and delimiter positions.

> Expected Results
>
> 1. twitter.com/dog_rates/status/892420643555336193/photo/1
> 2. twitter.com/dog_rates/status/878281511006478336/photo/1
> 3. twitter.com/dog_rates/status/812503143955202048/photo/1
> 4. twitter.com/dog_rates/status/810984652412424192/photo/1
> 5. twitter.com/dog_rates/status/888804989199671297/photo/1

Comment: How do you decide when the desired URL ends? With a comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    'twitter.com/dog_rates/status/892420643555336193/photo/1',         
    'www.gofundme.com/3yd6y1c,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/878281511006478336/photo/1',
    'm.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=1888712391349242&id=1506300642923754&refsrc=ht.co%2FURVffYPPjY&_rdr,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/812503143955202048/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/812503143955202048/photo/1',
    'www.gofundme.com/sams-smile,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/810984652412424192/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1',
    'twitter.com/dog_rates/status/888804989199671297/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/888804989199671297/photo/1'
]

df=pd.DataFrame({'url':data})
df['res'] = df['url'].str.split(',').str[-1]
```

just extract last value split by `,`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_data = [
    'twitter.com/dog_rates/status/892420643555336193/photo/1',         
    'www.gofundme.com/3yd6y1c,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/878281511006478336/photo/1',
    'm.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=1888712391349242&id=1506300642923754&refsrc=ht.co%2FURVffYPPjY&_rdr,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/812503143955202048/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/812503143955202048/photo/1',
    'www.gofundme.com/sams-smile,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/810984652412424192/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1',
    'twitter.com/dog_rates/status/888804989199671297/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/888804989199671297/photo/1'
]



final_results = []
pattern= 'twitter.com/dog_rates/'
​
for row in my_data:
    splited_row = row.split(',')
    for recod in splited_row:
        if recod.startswith(pattern):
            final_results.append(recod)
            break

In [10]:

final_results
Out[10]:
['twitter.com/dog_rates/status/892420643555336193/photo/1',
 'twitter.com/dog_rates/status/878281511006478336/photo/1',
 'twitter.com/dog_rates/status/812503143955202048/photo/1',
 'twitter.com/dog_rates/status/810984652412424192/photo/1',
 'twitter.com/dog_rates/status/888804989199671297/photo/1']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this  ... just load each of the rows in as a string.

```
data= [ "twitter.com/dog_rates/status/892420643555336193/photo/1",
"www.gofundme.com/3yd6y1c,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/878281511006478336/photo/1",
"m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=1888712391349242&id=1506300642923754&refsrc=ht.co%2FURVffYPPjY&_rdr,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/812503143955202048/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/812503143955202048/photo/1",
"www.gofundme.com/sams-smile, twitter.com/dog_rates/status/810984652412424192/photo/1, twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1, twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1, twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1, twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1",
"twitter.com/dog_rates/status/888804989199671297/photo/1, twitter.com/dog_rates/status/888804989199671297/photo/1"
]
```

Now we can split the data into each of the sentences using ",".

```
results=[]
for row in data:
    urls=row.split(",")
    for i in urls:
        if(i.strip().startswith("twitter.com/dog_rates/")):
            results.append(i.strip())
            break
```

We will get the results in the `results` variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this using `import re`

```
import re
input = '''1. twitter.com/dog_rates/status/892420643555336193/photo/1 (desired version)

2. www.gofundme.com/3yd6y1c,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/878281511006478336/photo/1

3. m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=1888712391349242&id=1506300642923754&refsrc=ht.co%2FURVffYPPjY&_rdr,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/812503143955202048/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/812503143955202048/photo/1

4. www.gofundme.com/sams-smile,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/810984652412424192/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/709901256215666688/photo/1

5. twitter.com/dog_rates/status/888804989199671297/photo/1,twitter.com/dog_rates/status/888804989199671297/photo/1'''
input=input+'\n'

regex='(twitter.com/dog_rates/status/\d*/photo/1).*\n'

twitter_list = re.findall(regex,input)
i=1
for item in twitter_list:
    print(str(i)+'. '+item)
    i+=1
```